Why isn't my async method called immediately in C#
Caller:
var snapshotMessages = snapshotRepository.GetMessages();
_ = Console.Error.WriteLineAsync("Loading XML timetables...");
// some lengthy operation which loads a large dataset from a SQL database
await foreach (var item in snapshotMessages) {
    // process the item
}

Callee:
    public async IAsyncEnumerable<Pport> GetMessages() {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Start getting messages");
        var timestamp = DateTime.MinValue;
        // some code which start downloading a large file from FTP
    }

I want to parallelise the database loading and the download. However, the "Start getting messages" line doesn't appear, which indicate the program doesn't behave in parallel as I expect.
The documentation says that:

An async method runs synchronously until it reaches its first await expression, at which point the method is suspended until the awaited task is complete. In the meantime, control returns to the caller of the method, as the example in the next section shows.

which doesn't seem to be true here. What have I done wrong?

This is behaving the same way as a non-async iterator block: until you start iterating, no code runs.

I don't understand. Doesn't the code need to run before an iterable is returned?

Not the code you wrote in your method, no. The compiler generates a method which effectively builds a state machine, and runs the code from your method on a "lazy" basis when the iterable is consumed. I'd strongly recommend making sure you understand sync iterator blocks first, then look at async iterator blocks.

No need to close this question, it's actually quite educational. While my first instinct is that he's using the wrong tool (it should probably be Task<IEnumerable<...>>), and after you know the answer it seems obvious, I wouldn't have necessarily thought that calling an IAsyncEnumerable wouldn't call it's non-async portion.

Related: How to enumerate an IAsyncEnumerable and invoke an async action for each element, allowing concurrency for each iteration/action pair?

What is the intention behind the _ = Console.Error.WriteLineAsync("Loading XML timetables...");, as opposed to the simpler Console.WriteLine("Loading XML timetables...");?

Because I don't want Console.WriteLine from blocking the thread.

Iterators - both synchronous and asynchronous - have deferred execution - basically, the state machine is inactive until the actual foreach. However, you can fix this easily by restructuring a little:
public IAsyncEnumerable<Pport> GetMessages()
{
    // note: this is neither "async" nor has "yield"

    Console.Error.WriteLine("Start getting messages");
    var timestamp = DateTime.MinValue;
    return GetMessagesCore(timestamp);
}
private async IAsyncEnumerable<Pport> GetMessagesCore(DateTime timestamp)
{
    // some code which start downloading a large file from FTP
    ... yield etc
} 

This approach is also often used to allow only the private method to have the [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken parameter for use with WithCancellation()

However! An async iterator block - like a regular iterator block - is only a single passive pump allowing a sequence to be fetched iteratively; it is not an actively parallel / concurrent machine. For that you probably want a Channel<T>, i.e. Channel<Pport> with a separate worker initiated via Task.Run (or similar), so you have an active producer/consumer pair with some constrained or unconstrained device between them (the Channel<T>). A channel has the ReadAllAsync() API which exposes the channel as IAsyncEnumerable<T>.
For example:
await foreach(var i in new Foo().GetMessages())
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
class Foo
{
    public IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetMessages()
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Start getting messages");
        // use a bounded channel as a buffer of 10 pending items;
        // there is also an unbounded option available
        Channel<int> channel = Channel.CreateBounded<int>(
            new BoundedChannelOptions(capacity: 10));
        _ = Task.Run(() => Produce(channel.Writer));
        return channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync();
    }

    private async Task Produce(ChannelWriter<int> writer)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                await writer.WriteAsync(i);
            }
            writer.TryComplete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            writer.TryComplete(ex);
        }
    }
}


Your "fix" hasn't fixed the problem.  It's just changed the logging such that the logs suggest the code is working as intended even though it's not.  The OP wants their long running operation to run at the same time as their GetMessagesCore method, which wouldn't change with this.

@Servy that depends on your perspective; some code has now run immediately - but yes, if OP wants a fully active pump, that's something different - I will clarify

Yes, the code that claims work has been started has run immediately, and the work it claims has been started has not actually started running.  That's actively counter-productive in their situation, as it makes the logging think they are doing what they want even though it isn't.

@Servy happier? (see edit)
